# Failed Pass Parameter to Web Service in Mule

Tags: web-services, parameter-passing, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I call the Operation from SOAP using Web Service Consumer component, and I want to pass the parameter using Transform Message.

[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BOZA.jpg)

I set Java Class in Transform Message, and declared the parameter.

[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkdx7.jpg)

When I run the app, I get error.
This is the error :

> ---
>
> Message               : Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.util.LinkedHashMap, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}".
>   Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException
>   Code                  : MULE_ERROR-236
>
> ---

How can I pass the parameter ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked one of my SOAP connections where I use Dataweave, and the output type is "application/xml". Can you try using that instead of "application/java"? Also, you may want to define the XMLNS namespace using the Dataweave namespace directive.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#namespace-directive

Answer (score 0):

You can read this tutorial for more information about transformer message: 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/xmlobject-transformers

Best Regards,
Giuseppe.